# how can i pass both int and string values to an execute UPDATE of a table

Tags: python, database, sqlite, sql-update

I want to pass a string value and an integer value to a sqlite3 execute UPDATE command

the `num` var needs to be an `Int type`, and the `ans` var needs to be `String type` so I could change the table's contents properly.

the table:

```
q_conn = sqlite3.connect('questions_stack.db')
q_c = q_conn.cursor()
q_c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS questions (
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
            topic TEXT,
            username TEXT,
            subject TEXT,
            body TEXT,
            likes INTEGER,
            comments TEXT)                  
            """)
```

here I'm trying to `UPDATE` a certain column of a certain row:
    def update_comments():

```
    q_c.execute("""SELECT comments FROM questions WHERE id = ?""", (int(num),))
    previous_comments = q_c.fetchone()
    q_c.execute("""UPDATE questions SET comments = ? WHERE id = ?""",
            (str(previous_comments) + "\n" + str(ans), int(num)))
    q_conn.commit()
```

however, in my `questions` sqlite3 database table the `comments` column update I made appears as:

```
(u'',)
comment1
```

and when the `update_comments()` function is called again the comments column contains:

```
(u"(u'',)\ncomment1",)
comment2
```

what is the problem? and how can I fix it? does it have anything to do with the fact i passed both INT and STRING values to the command?

Comment: the `num` var contains a string digit value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that this statement:

```
previous_comments = q_c.fetchone()
```

assigns a **tuple**, not a string. This tuple consists of one item - initially an empty string, because that's how you initialize your database - but still it is a tuple and when you call `str()` on it, you get the string representing a tuple, ie. `(u'',)`.

A proper way of doing it is either:

```
(previous_comments,) = q_c.fetchone()
```

or

```
previous_comments = q_c.fetchone()[0]
```

so that `previous_comments` is assigned a string value. Oh, and calling `str()` on a string is redundant, so you can simplify this:

```
q_c.execute("""UPDATE questions SET comments = ? WHERE id = ?""",
        (str(previous_comments) + "\n" + str(ans), int(num)))
```

to:

```
q_c.execute("""UPDATE questions SET comments = ? WHERE id = ?""",
        (previous_comments + "\n" + ans, int(num)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! @Błotosmętek. I really appreciate that :)